# GWT + Spring hosted mode not working

Tags: spring, gwt, gwt-hosted-mode

I have a following problem, probably somebody can help me?

I had an Spring MVC application, quite basic one, with a few simple jsp pages.

Also I had an Spring Security integrated with it.

Now I need to add some GWT widget to one page. No problem so far, I've added <div> to the page, added GWT module, all all needed GWT logic.

When I compile GWT and then deploy application to tomcat - everything works perfectly, I open app, login into it, open my page and see GWT UI components.

Now I want to open my application in **hosted mode**. There problems begin.

When I start hosted mode, Jetty starts, Spring framework initialize, and then my jsp (translated as .htm) open without hosted mode param ?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997. After opening my page I see nothing if I delete compiled gwt code.

When I manually add "?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997" hosted mode start and GWT module begin to load. This is when I get an error:

> 12:57:15.589 [ERROR] [rehabrental] Failed to load module 'testmodule'
>   from user agent  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru;
>   rv:1.9.2.23) Gecko/20110920 Firefox/3.6.23'  at 127.0.0.1:63260
>
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: warningThreshold     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.getCompilerOptions(JdtCompiler.java:413)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.<init>(JdtCompiler.java:228)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:700)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:235)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:447)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:370)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:360)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase$UiBrowserWidgetHostImpl.createModuleSpaceHost(DevModeBase.java:110)
>   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:197)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you use eclipse ?. If so you need rearrange your exported modules as JDT classes causes problems with the GWT compiler. See comment #7 in this [GWT issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4479) about pushing GWT dependencies above others, so that they are picked up first by the compiler.

Comment: OK, this particular error was because I was using Jetty7 instead of default Jetty6 in GWT.
After I removed Jetty7 from run configuration, page with GWT started to work.
But unfortunately all other pages became broken, and now I have error with
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELException

Still have no idea how to fix it. After I added el-api.jar to classpath, I immediatle got another error with AbstractMethodError

Comment: You'd better run in [`-noserver` mode](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT's) then.